# emails not sending from CentOS 5.6 VM on Win7 via PHP code

Tags: centos, email, windows-7, sendmail, localhost

I am experiencing an issue where my CentOS 5.6 (Final) VM running on Windows 7 has stopped sending emails from my PHP code.

I'm confident this isn't a coding issue as I have the exact same code running in my office and emails send correctly from there, hence why I believe this to be a networking/configuration issue.

In my `/etc/hosts/` file on my VM I have the following:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
192.168.0.9 crmpicco.co.uk m.crmpicco.co.uk dev53.localdomain
```

When I run `setup` on my VM the DNS configuration is set to `dev53.localdomain` and my Primary DNS is `192.168.0.1`.

In My `/var/log/maillog` files I see a lot of this sort of thing:

```
Nov 19 14:36:58 dev53 sendmail[21696]: qAJEawI7021696: from=<client.care@crmpicco.co.uk>, size=12858, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<1353335817.9103820024efb30b451d006dc4ab3370@PHPMAILSERVER>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]
Nov 19 14:36:58 dev53 sendmail[21693]: qAJEawvd021693: to=newbie@fletcher.co.uk, ctladdr=client.care@crmpicco.co.uk (48/48), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=42681, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (qAJEawI7021696 Message accepted for delivery)
Nov 19 14:36:59 dev53 sendmail[21698]: qAJEawI7021696: to=<newbie@fletcher.co.uk>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=132858, relay=mailserver.fletcher.co.uk. [213.171.216.114], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
```

Is this likely to be a configuration issue? Where should I be looking for a solution to this problem? Also, do I need to define a FQDN?

Answer (score 0):

```
Nov 19 14:36:59 dev53 sendmail[21698]: qAJEawI7021696: to=<newbie@fletcher.co.uk>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=132858, relay=mailserver.fletcher.co.uk. [213.171.216.114], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
```

The remote mail server at 213.171.216.114 couldn't be reached. Make sure you can actually reach this mail server from where you are (i.e. outgoing mail isn't blocked by your ISP) and that the server isn't rejecting connections from your address (i.e. the server refuses to talk to you).

Comment: When I try and telnet to the host with `telnet 213.171.216.114 25` I get the following: 
`Trying 213.171.216.114...
Connected to smtp-in-114.livemail.co.uk (213.171.216.114).
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp-in-109.livemail.co.uk ESMTP Postfix
421 Error: timeout exceeded
Connection closed by foreign host.` Is this pointing to a blocked port 25 via my ISP (CarphoneWarehouse/TalkTalk)?

Comment: No, the problem is at the other end.

Comment: By "other end" do you mean 213.171.216.114 is not accepting requests from my IP address? FWIW, my office IP (where my setup works) has a static IP, whereas my IP when working from home does not.

Answer (score 0):

Since you connect to port 25 at the remote site and then the connection gets dropped, there may be a problem with TCP window scaling. Please try to see if the problem gets bypassed (bypassed, not solved) using [the suggestion given here](https://serverfault.com/a/444666/25640).